# Best way to load AngularJs modules

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

I would like to implement a dynamic page what get list of name of modules from server and after it, it will load all modules what was in that list. For example if it get a table module, then load a table to that page. What should be the best solution for this?

Comment: AngularJS is single page application. Its worst to interact with Server side persistence without using an API. What you think about, if you talking about modules?

Comment: I search something like this: http://ngmodules.org/modules/loadOnDemand
just I need a simpler, easier version, because I am not allowed to use external libraries.